# How to track views of each post and which user has made them(and display view count)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I am currently working on a twitter-like website and am struggling with adding views. Previously, views worked well, but were only tracking every view ofthe post, not the user_id of the person viewing the post, which I need to track in order to display a statistic of most-active users on a different page.

I currently get this error message:
undefined method `views_count' for nil:NilClass

which links me to my post.html file, which containt

```
<h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-secondary"><%= @post.views_count %> zhlédnutí</h6>
```

the @post.views_count is defined in my post_controller.rb, which contains:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authorize_user!, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts or /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1 or /posts/1.json
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    record_view(@post)
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts or /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to post_url(@post), notice: "Post was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1 or /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to post_url(@post), notice: "Post was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1 or /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy!

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: "Post was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:body, :title)
    end

    def record_view(post)
      begin
        if current_user
          post.views.create(user_id: current_user.id)
        else
          post.views.create
        end
      rescue => e
        puts "Error creating view: #{e.message}"
      end
    end

    def authorize_user!
      unless current_user == @post.user
        flash[:alert] = "You are not authorized to perform this action."
        redirect_to root_path
      end
    end
  end
```

I feel like there is an obvious fix that I am completely missing. I'm very new to RoR, please forgive any stupid mistakes. I can provide more context if required. Help!

I have tried removing the @ from @Post.view_count, as this has caused me an error in the past. I cannot find the view_count anywhere in my code, but I have no idea what else I would use to display the view count.

Comment: If `@post.views_count` throws that error it means `@post` is nil, which means the post wasn’t found or it isn’t passed correctly to the view.

Comment: @DaveNewton Is there anything in my current code I can add or fix to avoid this issue? I can provide more snippets

Comment: Put a debugger/pry/whatever-you're-using in `show` and start debugging. The view hierarchy isn't super-clear, e.g., make sure you're looking at the correct template file etc.

Comment: Which action are you getting the error in? Show? It looks like it should be setting @post correctly, but you could put a 'debugger' statement in various places to check that it is set, and narrow your search to figure out why it's nil.

Also, post.views_count is not defined in your controller. Normally that would be defined in the Post model.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the first line of your PostsController:

```
before_action :set_post, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
```

You are only calling set_post for your edit, update, and destroy actions. You should add `:show` to that list

```
before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Comment: The show action retrieves the post in its body, no?

Comment: I haven't run into any issues with not including :show in set_post. Thanks for the input tho! Do you have any idea why the undefined methid error is happening?